# JS Google Geocode - Finding Address from Longitude and Latitude

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude, geocode

I have 3 variables longitude, latitude and address.

```
var long = ##;
var lat = ##;
var address = "";
```

Can I convert the long and lat that I have into an address which I can save in the address variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Google Maps API.

here is an link for reverse Geocoding.
[REVERSE GEOCODING GOOGLE API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)